# When the Plethystic sum converges?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

We have 
\begin{align}
& \exp\left(-\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{p}\right) = 1-x, \\
& \exp\left(-\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k} x_k^p}{p}\right) = \prod_{k}(1 - x_k).
\end{align}
When do $\exp\left(-\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{p}\right)$ and $\exp\left(-\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k} x_k^p}{p}\right)$ converge?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the interval of convergence of the power series $S(x)=\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{x^p}{p}$ using a standard tool,  namely the ratio test.  Applying the ratio test, we find that the series converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$.

For $x=1$ the series is the Harmonic series, which diverges.  For $x=-1$, the series is the alternating harmonic series, which converges to $-\log(2)$.  Therefore, the interval of convergence is $-1\le x<1$.

Next, we will show that for $-1\le x<1$, the series

$$\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{x^p}{p}=-\log(1-x)$$

To show this, we write for $|x|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{p=1}^N \frac{x^p}{p}&=\sum_{p=1}^N \int_0^x t^{p-1}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x \sum_{p=1}^Nt^{p-1}\\\\
&=\int_0^x\frac{1-t^N}{1-t} \,dt\\\\
&=-\log(1-x)-\int_0^x\frac{t^N}{1-t}\,dt
\end{align}$$

It is easy to show (e.g., Apply the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), or simply integrate by parts with $u=1/(1-t)$ and $v=t^{N+1}/(N+1)$) that for $-1\le x<1$,

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x\frac{t^N}{1-t}\,dt=0$$

whereby we conclude immediately for $-1\le x<1$

$$\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{x^p}{p}=-\log(1-x)$$

as was to be shown!